# ModemManager - Unable to to send SMS with curly braces

Tags: modem, mobile, sms

I'm stuck on a problem using ModemManager (mmcli 1.14.2) to programmatically send SMS which contains a certain combination of special characters which I have yet to identify.

The SMS I'm trying to send is the following:

```
OK({ yRgK1DNXQKo4C7uK43WnHArW1XbNekn6JJ80qgMTRcPM8pgGTJMwYDgseRRYOEA6NdCgQNgiSoheRZnK0czZy5P0GTny3rRrSEE9HTiFepFnhDxM6B2J3bpbHnHJiYbSQt40rt0dwIoZYeiEYyo7glw1kswTrg7He5Ojl8ysyxF4X54SCQomZrKRPsrEHpT2vLjCLfGn9pDGHxodwXbbKADm8j4waiGVnZfRBJBDSx8VUO28Yit068aM32t9a91NC0eUVkyUEGkNsm75cVQ7KJ0rpzucTRSudO7DJLxrgetz })
```

*I'm using a random string here just to simulate a large payload. In reality, the payload between curly braces is a more structured model*.

**The problem is that whenever I use the curly braces to encapsulate the payload, the message is not delivered to the recipient.**

I'm facing this issue using the following send methods.

### Using MMCLI

Sending SMS using mmcli with:

```
mmcli -m 1 --messaging-create-sms="number=<NUMBER>,text='OK({yRgK1DNXQKo4C7uK43WnHArW1XbNekn6JJ80qgMTRcPM8pgGTJMwYDgseRRYOEA6NdCgQNgiSoheRZnK0czZy5P0GTny3rRrSEE9HTiFepFnhDxM6B2J3bpbHnHJiYbSQt40rt0dwIoZYeiEYyo7glw1kswTrg7He5Ojl8ysyxF4X54SCQomZrKRPsrEHpT2vLjCLfGn9pDGHxodwXbbKADm8j4waiGVnZfRBJBDSx8VUO28Yit068aM32t9a91NC0eUVkyUEGkNsm75cVQ7KJ0rpzucTRSudO7DJLxrgetz})'"
```

and then

```
mmcli -m 1 --sms <id> --send
```

Which gives the following result:

> successfully sent the SMS

### Using DBUS

I use the [Messaging](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem.Messaging.html) DBUS interface to create a new [SMS](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Sms.html#gdbus-property-org-freedesktop-ModemManager1-Sms.Text3), set its "number" and "text" (UTF8 string) properties and then send it using its `Send()` method.

I use C# and [Tmds.Dbus](https://github.com/tmds/Tmds.DBus) to interact with the bus.

### The problem

Using both methods, I'm unable to receive the message on the recipient's phone.
If I try to send the same message **without** curly braces, it gets delivered without any problme.
If I try to send another message **with** curly braces (something like "*OK({Test})*" it still gets delivered without any problem.
If I try to send any of the above messages from a phone to the device I'm using (with modem manager) they get received without any problem (with or without curly braces, long and short version).

It seems like there's a special combination of chars which causes problem to ModemManager and therefore does not get sent.

The fact the same message can be sent from a phone to ModemManager makes me think there isn't any problem on the mobile operator side.

Unluckly, since the actual payload contains a JSON encoded model, curly braces are important.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send a buffer of 309 chars. SMS has a limit (of 104).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the OP states _"If I try to send the same message without curly braces, it gets delivered without any problem"_, so your explanation is unlikely to tackle the issue.